# Template not updating after model changed

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I iterate over an array containing objects:

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of files | orderBy: 'id':ascending:true | paginate: {id: 'FilePagination',itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: p}">
    <th [innerHTML]="project.files.indexOf(file)+1" scope="row"></th>
    <td><a href="{{file.uri + token}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa"
                                                          [class.fa-file-audio-o]="types.audio.includes(file.type)"
                                                          [class.fa-file-pdf-o]="types.document.includes(file.type)"></i>{{"
        " + file.fullName}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{file.size}}</td>
    <td>{{file.timestamp | timeCalc}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="adminMode">
        <button type="button" (click)="deleteFile(file)"
                class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-link p-0" title="Löschen"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Calling the deleteFile method:

```
deleteFile(file: File) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.fileService.deleteFile(file).subscribe(
        message => this.information = message,
        error => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.errorMessage = error;
        },
        () => {
            this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(file), 1);
            this.loading = false;
        }
    )
}
```

After the the subscription call is complete, the deleted file is not removed from the view. Still, it is definitely removed from array, as the index of all files in the array changed. Here are two screenshots showing the weird behavior:

Before deletion:
[image: beforeDelte]

---

After deletion:
[image: afterDelete]

Comment: That code works for me, so this is quite the headscratcher.

The instance of the object in the view is the exact same instance as what's being removed, right?

http://plnkr.co/edit/lSf7NX85HSDv4frgnXCc?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to exclude the element you want by an object property and reassign:

`this.files = this.files.filter(file => file.id !== fileToRemove.id);`

Plunker which is minimable and verifiable: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Comment: I think splice returns the removed element. Wouldnt that assign this element to this.files?

Comment: The linked Plunker doesn't have the assignment, you are correct, though! My error in leaving it in there.

Comment: Hm, my IDE points an "argument types dont match parameters" error. When i try to delete a file, this will automatically delete the file at the zeroth index in the array.

Comment: I should downvote me. If it's possible to use the array.filter method then this alternative should work correctly.

I really need to brush up on my JS array manipulation since it's garbage.

Comment: Hey man, at least you trying to help. Thumbs up! And also thumbs up, because your solution is working!! Thanks man!! Edit: But I would love to know, why splicing does not work...

Answer (score 0):

**Use project.files**

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of project.files | orderBy: 'id':ascending:true | paginate: {id: 'FilePagination',itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: p};">
    <th [innerHTML]="project.files.indexOf(file)+1" scope="row"></th>
    <td><a href="{{file.uri + token}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa"
                                                          [class.fa-file-audio-o]="types.audio.includes(file.type)"
                                                          [class.fa-file-pdf-o]="types.document.includes(file.type)"></i>{{"
        " + file.fullName}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{file.size}}</td>
    <td>{{file.timestamp | timeCalc}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="adminMode">
        <button type="button" (click)="deleteFile(file)"
                class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-link p-0" title="Löschen"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Delete function**:

```
deleteFile(file: File) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.fileService.deleteFile(file).subscribe(
        message => this.information = message,
        error => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.errorMessage = error;
        },
        () => {
            this.project.files.splice(file, 1);
            this.loading = false;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work, due to two things:
- the index from ngFor is not accurate for me, because the pagination leds to permutation between the index and the index of the file
- your way still does not remove the element from dom. I am still getting the annoying 0..

Comment: Give that a shot, changed to project.files

Comment: Does not change a thing. I marked @silentsod answer as correct. Thanks anyway, sir!